# Backup Battery For Macbook Pro

Tags: laptop, battery

I'm going on a very long flight soon and would like to use my Macbook Pro for as long as I can during the flight.

I see a long list of external power packs on Amazon, but none of these appear to have an output that's capable of plugging my Macbook Pro in to.

Is there a nice device to convert these types of plugs so I can use an external power pack to charge my Macbook Pro while travelling?  Or what's the best way to keep my laptop powered during this long flight (where there will be no power outlets).

Comment: Well just typing "macbook pro portable battery pack" into Google yields http://www.hypershop.com/HyperJuice-External-Battery-for-MacBook-iPad-iPhone-USB-s/91.htm which looks pretty compatible. What's the concern?

Comment: "Or what's the best way to keep my laptop powered during this long flight?"  Close lid.  Nap.

Comment: @ta.speot.is My understanding was that they're currently and have been in lawsuits with Apple over patent infringement (and has previously had to stop offering some products). I was hoping for a solution that might stick around for awhile, and was officially supported.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Sure, but any useful suggestion for us mere mortals that would like to work on those long flights?

Comment: @omghai2u - There's no way that Apple could claim infringement on that battery pack, since it accepts the standard Apple cigarette lighter plug and hence is really a generic unit.  And even if they did, once you owned the unit they wouldn't be able to take it away from you.

Comment: @DanielRHicks not the battery pack, the cable that connects the laptop to the outlet.  If you check their site they suggest two methods: the second method requires cutting wires (obviously not scalable, or fulfills my requirement of being COTS/supported by Apple); the first method requires purchasing a component from Apple that has been discontinued (which again isn't supported).

Comment: Hard to believe Apple doesn't have a cigarette lighter plug.  But what you're saying is that there's no way (short of an inverter), since Apple doesn't support any sort of operation off "mains".

Comment: @DanielRHicks Well, that's why I asked the question: it doesn't appear they do.  But I was hoping that maybe the superuser community would have alternatives besides "don't use your computer".

Comment: Well, there's always the inverter.

Comment: http://www.duracellpower.com/portable-power/power-packs/powerpack-300.aspx